# Any subset of a measurable set of finite measure have a finite covering?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, compactness, borel-sets

I want to be sure that any subset of a measurable set of finite measure has a finite covering.

This question is because, I have seen that for any measurable set E of finite measure, for each $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an open set $O$ which is a finite union of disjoint intervals and covers the set $E$, with $m(O\setminus E) < \epsilon$. That means the difference between the set and the open set is less than epsilon for any epsilon and the set $O\setminus E$ have measure 0. But in some proofs, I have seen that even when we the set in which we are working is compact (ex: [0,1] or [a,b]) they only assume the existence of the countable covering instead of the finite. Why? is that necessary? By Heine-Borel I know that every open covering has a finite subcover, so why complicate the problem with countable coverings when is easier to prove it by finite covers?.

Comment: A set of finite measure is not necessarily compact, so Heine-Borel does not guarantee that every open cover of a set of finite measure has a finite subcover. If there is a general proof that a subset of a measurable set of finite measure has a finite cover, then it will cover the case where the subset is compact.

Comment: @MichaelLee [0,1] is compact, and we have a subset of [0,1], which is measurable, the same finite covering of [0,1] will not cover the subset?

Comment: Can you provide a counter example to clear this in my mind?

Comment: Yes, a finite covering of $[0, 1]$ will cover a subset of $[0, 1]$, but not all sets of finite measure in $\mathbb{R}$ are compact. An example is $\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} [k, k+2^{-k}]$.